# How to use regular expressions in the output +-12aba to +-12

Tags: java, string, expression

How to use regular expressions in the output +-12aba to +-12, that is, except to a digital and minus symbol so far.

```
public class LeetCode8 {
public static int myAtoi(String str) {
    str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    System.out.println(str);
    if (!str.matches("[0-9]+")&&!str.matches("\\+[0-9]+")&&!str.matches("\\-[0-9]+")) {
        return 0;
    }
    str.replaceAll("", "0");
    if (str.length() > 10) {
        return 0;
    }
    long a = Long.valueOf(str);
    if (a > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int) a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = myAtoi("-12aba");
    System.out.println(i);
    //i want wo output -12
}
```

}

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: There is no code, but what I want to ask is how to convert string +-12aba into +-12 using regular expressions.

Comment: so you haven't tried anything !

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I tried many times, but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
private int myAtoi(String input){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\-|\\+)\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    if (!m.find())
        return 0;
    else
        return Integer.valueOf(m.group());
}
```